# With android phonegap loading email, click attachments no response

Tags: android, cordova, webview

with the chorme load the url when  click the attachments I can get the file dirs and choose file

```
public class MainEmailActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("//a email host address");
    }
}
```